# OpenCV does not accept ndarray to TextDecectorCNN.detect()

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to use [this OpenCV class](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d1/d66/classcv_1_1text_1_1TextDetectorCNN.html) of text detector to find out if I can use it for my project. I am loaging image like this:

```
src = cv2.imread(img_path)
```

And then I am trying to use function mentioned before like this:

```
bbox, confidence = cv2.text_TextDetectorCNN.detect(src)
```

But this code falls with the following mistake:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'detect' for 'cv2.text_TextDetectorCNN' objects doesn't apply to a 'numpy.ndarray' object
```

I have already tried to use `image = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB, cv2.CV_8UC3)` but it doesn't do a thing - `image` remains an ndarray.

UPD: Attaching whole code and problematic picture.

```py
import os


# borrowed from https://github.com/lengstrom/fast-style-transfer/blob/master/src/utils.py
def list_images(in_path, formats=[".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".png", ".pgm", ".bmp"]):
    img_files = []
    for (dirpath, _, filenames) in os.walk(in_path):
        for file in filenames:
            _, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
            ext = str.lower(ext)
            if ext in formats:
                img_files.append(os.path.join(dirpath, file))
    return img_files


def test_accuracy(folder_path):
    image_list = list_images(folder_path)
    for img_path in image_list:
        src = cv2.imread(img_path)
        bbox, confidence = cv2.text_TextDetectorCNN.detect(src)
        print(img_path, bbox, confidence) # To check format of output
```

Tested image: [image: image_1]
(I've tested 3 different `.jpg` images, none of them worked)

Question: is there a way to convert ndarray into some OpenCV format that will be accepted by mentioned function?

Comment: Could you put then image and the block of code you're having problem running?

Comment: Two given lines already causing a problem, but I have updated post with info you're asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't create an instance of your text detector. See this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

# After downloading the caffemodel and
# textbox.prototxt you have to create
# an instance of your model
textSpotter = cv2.text.TextDetectorCNN_create(
    "textbox.prototxt", "TextBoxes_icdar13.caffemodel"
)
src = cv2.imread("1.png")
bbox, confidence = textSpotter.detect(src)
print("HELLO", bbox, confidence)  # To check format of output
```

Comment: I though pretrained model was built into library, but I was wrong and to use it, I should download it firstly.

Links for both files can be found [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d66/classcv_1_1text_1_1TextDetectorCNN.html), in the top of the page.

Huge thanks, @FarhoodET